# How do I access a function that is being updated from a redux store properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have this component that I split for easy management. Before splitting everything worked as expected, after splitting I am getting an error when I click on an icon which calls the `createReactionsIcon`. Error says

```
TypeError: updateReaction is not a function
onClick
./components/home/components/SingleUpload.jsx:26
  23 | 
  24 |    return icons.map(({ key, text, type }) => (
  25 |        <IconText
> 26 |            onClick={() => updateReaction(item.id, key)}
     | ^  27 |            key={key}
  28 |            type={type}
  29 |            text={text}
```

How can I access this correctly from my `Home` component where `updateReaction` is returning `updateReaction` from the redux store.

SubComponent

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import { Avatar, Card, Icon, List } from 'antd';

import { LIST_TEXTS, STYLES } from '../constants';

const { AVATAR, CARD_CONTAINER, CARD_LIST, ICON, USER_LIST } = STYLES;
const { INNER, MORE, UPLOAD, VERTICAL } = LIST_TEXTS;

const IconText = ({ type, text, onClick }) => (
    <span>
        <Icon type={type} style={ICON} onClick={onClick} />
        {text}
    </span>
);
function createReactionsIcon(item, updateReaction) {
    const { like, dislike, maybe } = item.reactions;
    const icons = [
        { key: 'like', text: `${like.count}`, type: 'heart' },
        { key: 'dislike', text: `${dislike.count}`, type: 'dislike' },
        { key: 'maybe', text: `${maybe.count}`, type: 'meh' },
    ];

    return icons.map(({ key, text, type }) => (
        <IconText
            onClick={() => updateReaction(item.id, key)}
            key={key}
            type={type}
            text={text}
        />
    ));
}

export default class SingleUpload extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { values } = this.props;

        return (
            <div style={CARD_CONTAINER}>
                <List
                    itemLayout={VERTICAL}
                    dataSource={values}
                    renderItem={item => {
                        const { avatar, description, id, uploader: { image, name } } = item;

                        return (
                            <List.Item style={USER_LIST}>
                                <Card
                                    actions={createReactionsIcon(item, this.updateReaction)}
                                    cover={<img alt={UPLOAD} src={image} />}
                                    extra={<Icon type={MORE} />}
                                    hoverable
                                    key={id}
                                    title={(
                                        <a href="/">
                                            <Avatar src={avatar} style={AVATAR} />
                                            {name}
                                        </a>
                                )}
                                    type={INNER}
                                    style={CARD_LIST}
                                >
                                    {description}
                                </Card>
                            </List.Item>
                        );
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Home.js

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import SingleUpload from './SingleUpload';
import ComparisonUpload from './ComparisonUpload';
import { STYLES } from '../constants';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import { getUploads } from '../selectors';

const { CARD_CONTAINER } = STYLES;

class Home extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { actions: { requestUploadList } } = this.props;

        requestUploadList();
    }

    updateReaction = (id, reaction) => {
        const { actions: { updateReaction } } = this.props;
        const payload = { id, reaction };
        updateReaction(payload);
    }

    render() {
        const { uploads } = this.props;

        return (
            <div style={CARD_CONTAINER}>
                <SingleUpload values={[...uploads.values()]} />
                <ComparisonUpload values={[...uploads.values()]} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Home.propTypes = {
    actions: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.object),
    uploads: PropTypes.instanceOf(Map),
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    uploads: getUploads(state),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass your function to component as `props`,

```
<SingleUpload values={[...uploads.values()]} updateReaction = {this.updateReaction}/>
```

Now you can use this in your child component,

```
<IconText onClick={() => this.props.updateReaction(item.id, key)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `updateReaction` from your parent to child as a callback

```
<SingleUpload values={[...uploads.values()]} hanldeReaction={this.updateReaction} />
```

And you can access it in the child using `props.hanldeReaction`

```
    <Card actions={createReactionsIcon(item, this.props.hanldeReaction)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass down the `updateReaction()` event-handler you defined in Home as a prop to `SingleUpload`. Then you can access that prop from anywhere inside your component.

Which means we can cleanup the actions prop inside the Card since we only need to pass the item now.

```
<Card actions={createReactionsIcon(item)}
```

As well as `createReactionsIcon`, now we just call that prop directly inside the function

```
function createReactionsIcon(item) {
    const { like, dislike, maybe } = item.reactions;
    const icons = [
        { key: 'like', text: `${like.count}`, type: 'heart' },
        { key: 'dislike', text: `${dislike.count}`, type: 'dislike' },
        { key: 'maybe', text: `${maybe.count}`, type: 'meh' },
    ];

    return icons.map(({ key, text, type }) => (
        <IconText
            onClick={() => this.props.updateReaction(item.id, key)}
            key={key}
            type={type}
            text={text}
        />
    ));
}
```

Less redundant code overall which sounds like what you are trying to achieve.